# Finding a closed expression solution for an equation

Tags: solution-verification

Have been dealing with this equation for a while, but yet able to get a simple expression.

I have already done numerical solution and seems to be working just fine, but I would like to get a closed expression.

The problem is to find $x$ form the following:

$\frac{2LxB}{2Lx+\sqrt{b^2+x^2}} + 2b\sqrt{\frac{2LxB}{2Lx+\sqrt{b^2+x^2}}} = Ax^2$

What I tried:

$y^2 = \frac{2LxB}{2Lx+\sqrt{b^2+x^2}}$ So the equation above resumes to:

$y^2 + 2by = Ax^2$

Then found the solution for $y$:

$y = \sqrt{b^2+Ax^2} -b$.

Then, trying equating the above, with the definition of $y$:

$\frac{2LxB}{2Lx+\sqrt{b^2+x^2}} = (\sqrt{b^2+Ax^2} -b)^2$

However, the problem is the term inside the square root, since $A$ is present in only one of them.

Any trick or technique you may know to solve this?

Thanks folks!

Comment: what is $Lx$ ? $L \cdot x$ or $L_x$ ?

Comment: These are all independent factors. Meaning $L\cdot x$.

Comment: I cannot think of any viable analytic approach. Are you looking instead for an approximated solution ?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Well, I actually managed to get a numerical result using the Matlab solver, which worked fine for my immediate needs. But I would like to get a closed expression as it would look more elegant in my paper. Now, I'm just claiming the right x is given by the solution of such equation. But getting a closed expression would be great!.

Comment: well, a closed formula is always attainable by just going on in isolating the square roots and squaring. The matter is that you will reach to an equation with x elevated at something not less than $6$ and containing most of the lower powers of it. So it should not be much useful.  Probably you need instead an asymptotic approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, beside the trivial $x=0$, you face a quintic polynomial
$$-64 b^6 B^2 L^2+16 B^2 L^2 \left(L^2 \left(B-4 b^2\right)^2-4 (A+1)
   b^4\right)x-$$ $$8  \left(A B L^2 \left(A b^2 \left(B-4 b^2\right)+8 B \left(L^2
   \left(B-4 b^2\right)+b^2\right)\right)\right)x^2+$$ $$A^2  \left(A^2 b^4+8 B L^2
   \left(2 (A+2) b^2-B\right)+32 B L^4 \left(3 B-4 b^2\right)\right)x^3-$$ $$2 
   \left(A^3 \left(4 L^2-1\right) \left(A b^2+8 B L^2\right)\right)x^4+A^4 \left(1-4
   L^2\right)^2 x^5=0$$

So, no hope for a closed form solution.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. Yes, I also got the trivial $x=0$, but of course, not useful for my needs. So did you get that huge polynomial just by expanding our all factors? (just wondering)

Comment: @kennentropy. Do you know another way to do it ? The question is : are you looking for the first root only ? Is it small compared to $b$ ? May be, we could make some *approximations* of the solution. Just let me know. Cheers :-)